# CSS/Jscript caching issue

Tags: caching, stylesheet

I'm pretty new to web design and have recently been working on an [amatuer photography](http://www.lesleywilliamson.com) website.  I updated it on Sunday night, cleared cache etc on my home computer and it was all looking fine.

The problem is when I checked it from work, behind corporate firewall etc, some of the pages have changed, some have not.  For example the home page still shows old images that were replaced, whereas some of the gallery pages have new images on them but no new functionality or style (from css/js file).  I've renamed the js and css file and deleted old files to try to force the browser to get a new version but it still looks like it's using old version.

I'm concerned people visiting the site will have a strange/hybrid version of the site, could this be because it's being cached on corporate server somewhere rather than on individual workstation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parts of the site could be being cached by your corporate server infrastructure, notably, a Proxy Server. You can check this in your headers that come from your site. A tool like FireBug or Fiddler2 should identify if a Proxy has been involved. Sorry, I don't know the exact header to look for as I don't operate behind one at the moment to try and see.

Though why only part of your site is behaving this way is beyond me. Worth checking though.